# Array merging: Keeping literal variables

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

Let me just jump directly into my problem.

## The Build-up

I have some simple language files which just return an associative array containing the language strings (This is Laravel if that's of any help). Don't worry about the variable, that's just for demonstrational purposes.

**lang/en/common.php**:

```
<?php return [
"yes"=>"Yes",
"no"=>"No",
"hello"=>"Hello {$name}!",
"newstring"=>"This string does not exist in the other language file",
"random_number"=>"Random number: ".rand(1,10)
];
```

**lang/da/common.php**:

```
<?php return [
"yes"=>"Ja",
"no"=>"Nej",
"hello"=>"Hej {$name}!"
];
```

Now, as you can see, the index `newstring` doesn't exist in the danish language file. Instead of having to remember to add all the indexes all the language files instead of just one, I wrote a script, which basically does this:

```
$base_lang = require('lang/en/common.php');
$language_to_merge = require('lang/da/common.php');
$merged_lang = array_replace_recursive($base_lang, $language_to_merge);
file_put_contents('lang/da/common.php', var_export($merged_lang, true));
```

## The problem

So far, so good. Now, lets say that `$name = "John Doe";`. By the very nature of PHP, after running this script the `lang/da/common.php` will now be

```
<?php return [
    "yes"=>"Ja",
    "no"=>"Nej",
    "hello"=>"Hej John Doe!",
    "newstring"=>"This string does not exist in the other language file",
    "random_number"=>"Random number: 4"
    ];
```

As you might have guessed, the unwanted result is in the `hello` and `random_number`-indexes. Preferably it should still be `"hello"=>"Hej {$name}!"` and `"random_number"=>"Random number: ".rand(1,10)`, but obviously that ain't happening due to PHP parsing the array values, which basically tells me that this is the wrong strategy.

#### Wanted result:

```
<?php return [
    "yes"=>"Ja",
    "no"=>"Nej",
    "hello"=>"Hej {$name}!",
    "newstring"=>"This string does not exist in the other language file",
    "random_number"=>"Random number: ".rand(1,10)
    ];
```

## The "how the h.. do I do that?"

Any idea how to get around this? I could `file_get_contents()` and do some regex, but i worry that there's too many error sources involved in that.

Thanks in advance!

## EDIT

Some people have recommended using single quotes. While that actually answers my question, I became aware that I wasn't precise enough; when the Language class treats the files, I want the values to be parsed (the normal behaviour) - but only when I run my merge-script I want the actual literal variable references to remain intact.

## EDIT 2 - Temporary workaround

Until I find a proper solution for this, I'm just running through the arrays of the base language, checking for key existences in the language I'm trying to fill with the missing keys - and appending a comment to the bottom of those files.

Comment: so your problem is, that you do not want variables to be interpolated inside the strings? and treat it as literal strings?

Comment: You might have a look at the model that wikipedia uses for extensions, where all the languages are kept in associative arrays in one file -- you can load them all at once, and it's then easy to check whether a phrase exists in your choice of language, and if it doesn't, use the phrase from the "default" language.

Comment: @ialarmedalien - that's actually the way it works right now. What I want to do is merge the non-exisiting keys over to the other language files so I know what needs translation.

Comment: @Ghost - No, sorry for my lack of precision. See the edited post.

Comment: What if you remove every `$` found after a `{` before you merge the array, then you add them again? Just a quick thought...

Comment: @Adrenaxus Good point. That could actually work for the inline varaibles. But as stated in my edited post I also want to keep functions, like fx. `rand()` in the example. I'm using a temporary workaround now if you're interested. Editing the post now

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** See OP's comment. This is true, but not the answer to his question :)

You should use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
<?php return [
"yes"=>'Yes',
"no"=>'No',
"hello"=>'Hello {$name}!'
"newstring"=>'This string does not exist in the other language file'
];
```

PHP only parses variables inside double-quotes.

Comment: Correct; but I didn't make myself clear enough, sorry. Under normal circumstances (i.e. when the app actually uses the language file) I want it to actually parse the value. It's only when running the merge-script I want the literal variable name.

Comment: Ah ofcourse :)... In that case this is not the answer indeed.